# Значение переменной в fputs C++

Tags: c++

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    int main () {

        string login, password;
        string real_login = "admin";
        string real_password = "admin";
        FILE * file;
        file = fopen ("data.txt", "a");

        while (login != real_login || password != real_password) {

        cout << "Your login: ";
        cin >> login; 
        cout << "Your password: ";
        cin >> password;

        if(login != real_login || password != real_password) {
            cout << "such a user exists" << endl;

        }

        else {
            system("cls");
            if(file != NULL) { 
            fputs("login", file); 
            fclose(file);
            cout << "successfully ! please restart application" << endl; }

}}

    cout << "unknown computer: press any key to exit...";
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Вопрос: Как записать значение переменной в файл. 
fputs("login", file);  пробовал просто login без "" не получается, ошибка. 
P.S. Новичок :)

Comment: А что не работает? (Попробуйте выкинуть лишний код, оставьте только ту часть, которая воспроизводить проблему.)

Comment: ошибка такая: не существует подходящей функции преобразования  из "std::string" в "сonst char * "

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если вы пишете на C, не пользуйтесь `string` (а пользуйтесь `char*` и функциями наподобие `strcmp`). Если вы пишете на C++, не пользуйтесь `FILE*` (а пользуйтесь `fstream`).

Если вы всё же хотите сделать неправильно (`string` + `FILE*`), ситуацию исправит `login.c_str()`.

Comment: Позвольте, а вместо FILE * что использовать? я думал официально ерунды не скажут: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/?kw=fopen

Comment: @Дмитрий Астафьев: Во-первых, cplusplus.com далеко не официальный сайт. cppreference гораздо лучше.

Во-вторых, функциональность `FILE*` оставлена для обратной совместимости с C, пользоваться ей без осознанной необходимости не надо.

Comment: Извиняйте тогда, спасибо. Вот тут вот правильно про fstream ? 
http://prostocpp.narod.ru/filevv.html

Comment: @Дмитрий Астафьев: как-то там всё излишне сложно. Вам надо проще:

    ofstream file("data.txt"); 
    if (!file) { /* сообщить об ошибке и выйти */ }
    file << login << endl;

Comment: @VladD, а чем cppreference **гораздо лучше**, чем cplusplus?

IMHO примерно одна и та же нудятина (видимо это неотъемливое свойство языка, который оба описывают) и в обоих невозможно *быстро* найти подходящий пример.

--

@Дмитрий Астафьев, а сайтик, который Вам приглянулся -- Это нечто... 

(у меня просто слов нет).

Comment: @avp: на cplusplus.com встречаются неверные рекомендации и фактические ошибки. Мнение [отсюда](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972076/why-is-the-cplusplus-website-bad):

> cplusplus.com is not so bad as a reference, but the examples promote poor coding and the tutorials even more so. It's a melting pot of awful contributions. People keep coming on to Stack Overflow asking about why their crappy code isn't working, and they use `while (!myStream.eof())` and when quizzed as to why it turns out the cplusplus.com tutorials teach this.

Comment: @VladD, это известная  ссылка (и ей уже 2 года). 

Обратите внимание (там же)

    @MatheusMoreira: It was (slightly) wrong in a few places; now it's been (at least mostly) fixed. That won't stop people blindly asserting that it's still wrong, since a bad reputation can be difficult to lose. –  Mike Seymour Aug 15 '12 at 15:30 


с тех пор, конечно, могли и новых ошибок наделать.

(А кто нибудь тщательно проверял  cppreference)?

Comment: @avp: Ну давайте сами посмотрим. Вот [этот кусок](http://pastebin.com/Fc19QV2W) [отсюда](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/), считает себя tutorial'ом.

Отвлекаясь от того, что файл надо закрывать через RAII (иначе у вас в области видимости мёртвая переменная), код типа проверяет ошибки. На самом деле, нет: если ошибка происходит в `getline`, это никак не детектируется. (Не говоря уже о том, что самое [сложное и интересное](/questions/321669/c) — чтение попеременно чисел и строк — вовсе не рассматривается.)

Comment: @avp: ну или сравните <http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor> и <https://www.google.com/#q=copy+constructor+site:cplusplus.com> (а эта тема нужная, иначе возникают [интересные вопросы](/questions/194056/)).

Интересно, есть ли на cplusplus.com место, где объясняется разница между кодом:

    X x(y); // 1

    X x = y; // 2

и

    X x; x = y; // 3

? (Все три разные.)

Comment: @VladD, а что Вы хотите от короткого примера с построчным чтением файла?

IMHO пример, как пример, я бы, даже `close` поленился тут делать. 

Если в нем рассматривать тему смешения форматного ввода (в  C++ `instream >> var;`) с построчным (да еще добавить seek, read, ungetc и т.п.), то он бы вырос строк до 300 :). 

Про RAII (это же просто концепция) в этом контексте я вообще не понял.

Разница в уровне рассмотрения копирующего конструктора, конечно, есть.

--

И все-таки, лично я в большинстве случаев, легче воспринимаю информацию с  cplusplus.com (наверное, просто привычка).

Comment: @avp: Если это tutorial, и он пытается изобразить проверку ошибок, он должен делать это правильно. Или вообще не проверять, или проверять полностью, иначе создаётся ложное впечатление того, что код не игрушечный. Ну и tutorial **обязан** сообщать о проблемах с «потерянным» `\n`.

Идея с RAII вот какая: написать `{ ofstream file("data.txt"); /* проверки */ file << login << endl; }`. С закрывающей скобкой умрёт переменная и закроется файл. Если пользоваться `close()`, переменная останется, но пользоваться ей будет нельзя, фи. (Это ИМХО грех равносильный использованию глобальных переменных в C.)

Comment: @VladD, если в туториалах сообщать о всех проблемах, то честнее будет в преамбуле большими буквами написать --

С++ ЭТО СЛОЖНЫЙ ДЛЯ ИЗУЧЕНИЯ ЯЗЫК С КУЧЕЙ РАЗНЫХ ТРУДНОВЫЯВЛЯЕМЫХ ПРОБЛЕМ. 

Старайтесь НЕ ПИСАТЬ на нем!

Comment: @avp: ДА!!! С этого надо всегда начинать.

PS: это первые мои три восклицательных знака на этом форуме.